# How to remove default focus to the MAIN agenda, in Drools?

Tags: drools, kie

I'm using Drools 6.2.0

I want to group my rules in 3 groups (FIRST, MAIN, LAST),
and execute them in this order:

- FIRST
- MAIN
- LAST

To do this, I'm using **agenda-group "FIRST"** and **agenda-group "LAST"** in necessary rules. The other rules, by default belongs to the **MAIN** agenda.

I'm using this code to specify the order:

```
private void configureAgendas() {
    Agenda agenda = session.getAgenda();

    agenda.getAgendaGroup("LAST").setFocus();
    agenda.getAgendaGroup("MAIN").setFocus();
    agenda.getAgendaGroup("FIRST").setFocus();
}
```

My problem is that the MAIN agenda is always executed at the END.
So, I'm having the MAIN agenda executed twice:

- FIRST
- MAIN
- LAST
- MAIN (executed again. I want to skip this last execution)

How can I achive this?

If I cannot disable this auto-execution of MAIN agenda,
how can I create a rule that will be the last rule to be executed?

Note: I already tried with **salience Integer.MIN_VALUE**, but I still have rules of MAIN agenda being executed after this one.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to control rule execution in this way you should avoid the default group altogether and place all of your rule in one of "one", "two", "three".

Note that a rule attribute outside rule ... end is valid for all following rule until cancelled or changed, so there's no need to set the rule group per rule.

(It is strange that there are still MAIN rules firing after after MAIN and LAST are exhausted. I wouldn't like this scenario.)

EDIT: One other option is to add one rule in LAST with lowermost priority to change the focus to FIRST. You may need another one to "rewind" this last rule in LAST so that it fires again at the end of the next round.

Comment: Thanks @laune, I didn't expect this behaviour also. And my problem is worst, because I cannot change the other hundred rules, because they are still created in production database, etc. So, I need to work with rules in MAIN agenda + mine agendas...